# scp (secure copy) to ec2 instance without password

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, scp, pem

I have an EC2 instance running (FreeBSD 9 AMI ami-8cce3fe5), and I can ssh into it using my amazon-created key file without password prompt, no problem.

However, when I want to copy a file to the instance using scp I am asked to enter a password:

```
scp somefile.txt -i mykey.pem root@my.ec2.id.amazonaws.com:/

Password:
```

Any ideas why this is happening/how it can be prevented?

Comment: Are you using excatly the same identifier for the user and host?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by identifier, could you explain?

Comment: if for one connection you use an Ip address and for the other you use a name it will not work. I just saw that you use `-i` option to provide your identity. May be you should also show the command you use to log in with ssh.

Answer (score 968, accepted):

I figured it out.  I had the arguments in the wrong order.  This works:

```
scp -i mykey.pem somefile.txt root@my.ec2.id.amazonaws.com:/
```

Comment: from who understand how to connect to ec2 through ssh, just change the `ssh` command to `scp` and add the name file after the pem file.

Comment: Since this answer is a little old, a more recent example from my new EC2 instance: scp -i kp1.pem ./file.txt ec2-user@1.2.3.4:/home/ec2-user

Comment: I'm getting "No space left on device" when I execute this command.   scp -i /home/myusername/keypair.pem -r /home/myusername/digits/digits/jobs/20150724-111748-8bd3 ubuntu@ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-x.amazonaws.com:/home/ubuntu

Comment: @siliconrockstar Your statement `ec2-user@1.2.3.4:/home/ec2-user` is easily replaced with the shorter and easier `ec2-user@1.2.3.4:./` `./` FTW!

Comment: In my experience ~ and ./ operators don't always resolve correctly on remote machines, so I got into the habit of using the full path, but +1 if it's working for you.

Comment: One more way:
Create/edit ~/.ssh/config file and add remote-host entry there. Then,
`$ scp /source/file_to_copy.txt remote-user@remote-host:/destination`

Comment: A very late comment, but what @ClaudioSantos suggests doesn't work exactly if you're using a non-standard port. It's -p for ssh and -P for scp.

Comment: I can use my *.PEM file to ssh into ec2. however, when I want to use it to SCP a file, it gives me the "Permission Denied" error! How can I solve this?

Comment: @AleX_ try pscp (PuTTY with pscp) --> `pscp -i /path/to/your/.pemkey -r user@##-##-##-##:/path/to/files .` the trailing period just says to drop the files where you are. I got started with pscp here: https://www.ssh.com/ssh/putty/putty-manuals/0.68/Chapter5.html

Comment: Worked like a charm ! i was trying -i abc.pem at end. I reorderd as per your suggestion and it worked perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: @JoeParzival: and with macos terminal?

Comment: What if you want to cp from 1 remote instance to another. The following didn't work for me even through I can ssh to each server with the key scp -i mykey.pem root@one.ec2.id.amazonaws.com:/somefile.txt root@two.ec2.id.amazonaws.com:/

Comment: In case the .pem file doesn't have root permissions, one should enter the user path. for eg. In case of ubuntu, it is "/home/ubuntu". so the command becomes - "scp -i mykey.pem somefile.txt user@my.ec2.id.amazonaws.com:/home/ubuntu"

Answer (score 71):

```
scp -i /path/to/your/.pemkey -r /copy/from/path user@server:/copy/to/path
```

Comment: (-r) parameter is not required but it's required to remove (/) from the end of remote path.

Your example worked for me, Thanks a lot

Comment: how to delete existing from server before upload?

Answer (score 64):

**copy a file from a local server to a remote server**

```
sudo scp -i my-pem-file.pem ./source/test.txt ec2-user@1.2.3.4:~/destination/
```

**copy a file from a remote server to a local machine**

```
sudo scp -i my-pem-file.pem ec2-user@1.2.3.4:~/source/of/remote/test.txt ./where/to/put
```

So the basically syntax is:-

```
scp -i my-pem-file.pem username@source:/location/to/file username@destination:/where/to/put
```

`-i` is for the *identity_file*

Comment: Only this worked for me. Rest all failed. Thanks a ton

Answer (score 41):

I've used below command to copy from local linux Centos 7 to AWS EC2.

```
scp -i user_key.pem file.txt ec2-user@my.ec2.id.amazonaws.com:/home/ec2-user
```

Answer (score 22):

Making [siliconerockstar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/761967/siliconrockstar)'s comment an answer since it worked for me

```
scp -i kp1.pem ./file.txt ec2-user@1.2.3.4:/home/ec2-user
```

Answer (score 19):

```
scp -i ~/.ssh/key.pem ec2-user@ip:/home/ec2-user/file-to-copy.txt .
```

The file name shouldnt be between the pem file and the ec2-user string - that doesnt work. This also allows you to reserve the name of the copied file.

Answer (score 8):

lets assume that your pem file and somefile.txt you want to send is in Downloads folder

```
scp -i ~/Downloads/mykey.pem ~/Downloads/somefile.txt root@my.ec2.id.amazonaws.com:~/
```

let me know if it doesn't work

Comment: scp -i /Users/Username/Downloads/myfile.pem -r     ubuntu@my.ect.id.amazonaws.com:~/ ~/Desktop/

in case u want to transfer file from server to local

Comment: Thanks I got "access denied" with `:/` at the end but with `:~/` it works

Comment: yeah because :/ is root folder and :~/ is user folder so if you are root user then :/ or :~/ anything will work and if you are not root user then only :~/ you have to use.

Answer (score 4):

`scp -i /home/barkat/Downloads/LamppServer.pem lampp_x64_12.04.tar.gz`

this will be very helpful to all of you guys

Answer (score 3):

My `hadoopec2cluster.pem` file was the only one in the directory on my local mac, couldn't scp it to aws using `scp -i hadoopec2cluster.pem hadoopec2cluster.pem ubuntu@serverip:~`.

Copied hadoopec2cluster.pem to hadoopec2cluster_2.pem and then `scp -i hadoopec2cluster.pem hadoopec2cluster_2.pem ubuntu@serverip:~`. Voila!

Answer (score 2):

I was hung up on this because I was specifying my public key file in

```
scp -i [private key file path]
```

When I caught that mistake and changed it to the private key path instead, I was all set.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, the user `root` won't have any issues. But in certain cases where you're required to login under SSH as a different user, make sure the directory you're `scp`-ing has adequate permissions for the user you're SSH-ing.

Answer (score 2):

To use PSCP, you need the private key you generated in Converting Your Private Key Using PuTTYgen. You also need the public DNS address of your Linux instance

```
pscp -i C:\path\my-key-pair.ppk C:\path\Sample_file.txt ec2-user@public_dns:/home/ec2-user/Sample_file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

## For ec2 server

#move your key to /tmp or right folder on server

## Assign right permission

sudo chmod 600 /tmp/dev-sunrobotics-snippetbucketcom.pem

## then connect to server or transfer

scp   -i /tmp/dev-snippetbucketcom.pem filestore.tar.gz  ubuntu@85.111.5.33.98:/tmp

Make sure in your ip security you have allow ip address to connect

Answer (score 0):

write this code

```
scp -r -o "ForwardAgent=yes" /Users/pengge/11.vim root@192.168.2.228:/root/
```

If you have a SSH key with access to the destination server and the source server does not, adding -o "ForwardAgent=yes" will allow you to forward your SSH agent to the source server so that it can use your SSH key to connect to the destination server.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this syntax to copy file using scp and key

```
scp -i [key_file_path] source_path user@hostname:[dest_path]
```

Answer (score -6):

Just tested:

Run the following command:

```
sudo shred -u /etc/ssh/*_key /etc/ssh/*_key.pub
```

Then:

1. create ami (image of the ec2).
2. launch from new ami(image) from step no 2 chose new keys.