# Using scp to copy a file to Amazon EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, terminal, copy, scp, public-key

I am trying to use my Mac Terminal to scp a file from Downloads (phpMyAdmin I downloaded online) to my Amazon EC2 instance.

The command I used was:

```
scp -i myAmazonKey.pem phpMyAdmin-3.4.5-all-languages.tar.gz  hk22@mec2-50-17-16-67.compute-1.amazonaws.com:~/.
```

The error I got: 
**Warning: Identity file myAmazonKey.pem not accessible: No such file or directory.
Permission denied (publickey).
lost connection**

Both my myAmazonkey.pem and phpMyAdmin-3.4.5-all-languages.tar.gz are in Downloads, so then I tried

```
scp -i /Users/Hello_Kitty22/Downloads/myAmazonKey.pem /Users/Hello_Kitty22/Downloads/phpMyAdmin-3.4.5-all-languages.tar.gz  hk22@mec2-50-17-16-67.compute-1.amazonaws.com:~/.
```

and the error I got:
**Warning: Identity file /User/Hello_Kitty22/Downloads/myAmazonkey.pem not accessible: No such file or directory.
Permission denied (publickey).
lost connection**

Can anyone please tell me how to fix my problem?

p.s. there is a similar post: [scp (secure copy) to ec2 instance without password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558080/scp-secure-copy-to-ec2-instance-without-password)
but it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: I feel like when I start my Amazon instance online, I cannot access my local files in Downloads any more

Answer (score 548, accepted):

Try specifying the user to be `ec2-user`, e.g.

```
scp -i myAmazonKey.pem phpMyAdmin-3.4.5-all-languages.tar.gz ec2-user@mec2-50-17-16-67.compute-1.amazonaws.com:~/.
```

See [Connecting to Linux/UNIX Instances Using SSH](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html).

Comment: works great. Note that your user default user may be "ubuntu" if you are running a ubuntu instance.

Comment: of course copying to / may not work. Thanks for enlightening!

Comment: @DanielDropik I don't know if you're joking or not... but `:/` would try copy the folder to the root of the system, which would give permission errors on all machines without running sudo (or as root).

Comment: why it saying Please login as the user "ubuntu" rather than the user "root". what i need to do for copy

Comment: in my case i was using the user but , the difference i add the public dns mec2-50-17-16-67.compute-1.amazonaws.com instead of a domain name

Comment: I get
    ssh: connect to host ec2... port 22: Bad file number
    lost connection

Any ideas?

Comment: I had to switch around local file name and connection string, like this `scp -i myAmazonKey.pem ubuntu@mec2-50-17-16-67.compute-1.amazonaws.com:~/log.tar.gz log.tar.gz `

Comment: ``scp -i Test-2-Public-Key.pem Test-2-Private-Key.pem ubuntu@111.111.22.22:~/.``

When you need to copy your private instant pem file to your public instant root folder.

Answer (score 66):

second directory is your target destination, don't use server name there. In other words, you don't need to mention machine name for the machine you're currently in.

```
scp -i /path/to/your/.pemkey -r /copy/from/path user@server:/copy/to/path
```

-r if it's a directory.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. It was the only solution that worked for me.

Comment: scp -i "xyz.pem" -r file_xyz.zip user@server.region.compute.amazonaws.com:/path/

Answer (score 27):

Your key must not be publicly viewable for SSH to work. Use this command if needed:

```
chmod 400 yourPublicKeyFile.pem
```

Answer (score 18):

You should be on you local machine to try the above scp command.

On your local machine try:

```
scp -i ~/Downloads/myAmazonKey.pem ~/Downloads/phpMyAdmin-3.4.5-all-languages.tar.gz  hk22@mec2-50-17-16-67.compute-1.amazonaws.com:~/.
```

Answer (score 12):

Here are the details of what works for an **EC2** instance:

```
scp -i /path/to/whatever.pem /users/me/path-to-file ec2-user@ec2-55-55-555-555.compute-1.amazonaws.com:~
```

Few notes for beginning:

1. Note the spaces between the three parameters given after the `-i`
2. `scp` stands for secure copy protocol. Knowing the words makes it easier to remember the command.
3. `-i` dictates that you need to give the `.pem` file as the next param. If there is no `-i`, than you do not need a `.pem`.
4. Note the `:~` at the end of the destination for the EC2 instance.

Answer (score 10):

I had exactly same problem, my solution was to

`scp -i /path/pem -r /path/file/ ec2-user@public aws dns name:` (leave it blank here)

once you done this part, get into ssh server and mv file to desired location

Answer (score 10):

This just worked for me. I used a combination of two other answers to this question.

```sh
scp -i /Users/me/documents/myKP.pem -r /Users/me/desktop/testDir \
       ec2-user@ec2-11-111-11-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/home/ec2-user/remoteDir
```

The "ec2-user@ec2-11-111-11-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com" is copy-and-pasted from your ec2 instance's public DNS.

Comment: This worked for me while the other answers for some reason had no effect. Not sure what the problem was. Ubuntu 20.04 to ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 9):

**Send file from Local to Server:**

> scp -i .ssh/awsinstance.pem my_local_file
>   ubuntu@XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:/home/ubuntu

**Download file from Server to Local:**

> scp -i .ssh/awsinstance.pem 
>   ubuntu@XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:/home/ubuntu/server_file .

Comment: How do you know what your ubuntu@XX.XXX.XXX.XXX is? I'm using Windows though

Answer (score 7):

Below SCP format works for me

```
scp -i /path/my-key-pair.pem ec2-user@ec2-198-51-100-1.compute-1.amazonaws.com:~/SampleFile.txt ~/SampleFile2.txt
```

**SampleFile.txt**: It will be the path from your root directory(In my case, /home/ubuntu). in my case the file which I wanted to download was at /var/www

**SampleFile2.txt**: It will be path of your machine's root path(In my case, /home/MyPCUserName)

**So, I have to write below command**

```
scp -i /path/my-key-pair.pem ec2-user@ec2-198-51-100-1.compute-1.amazonaws.com:~/../../var/www/Filename.zip ~/Downloads
```

Answer (score 6):

```
scp -i ~/path to pem file/file.pem -r(for directory) /PATH OF LOCAL/localfile user@hostname:PATH OF SERVER/serverdirectory
```

Answer (score 6):

1. Public DNS

   ```
   scp -i /path/my-key-pair.pem /path/my-file.txt ec2-user@my-instance-public-dns-name:path/
   ```
2. (IPv6)

   ```
    scp -i /path/my-key-pair.pem /path/my-file.txt ec2-user@\[my-instance-IPv6-address\]:path/
   ```

Comment: works for me, lol, i actually use ~/path to target that

Answer (score 5):

try to use this command

if your instance is using ubuntu

```
scp -i myAmazonKey.pem phpMyAdmin-3.4.5-all-languages.tar.gz  ec2-user@mec2-50-17-16-67.compute-1.amazonaws.com:~/.
```

you can get more info about your instance from here
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/connection-prereqs.html

Answer (score 4):

> SCP Commend

**Send File from Local To Remote Server**

sudo scp -i ../Downloads/new_bb_key.pem ./dump.zip  ubuntu@13.127.124.129:~/.

**Send File from Remote Server To Local**

sudo scp -i  ~/Downloads/new_bb_key.pem  ubuntu@13.127.124.129:/home/ubuntu/LatestDBdump.zip Downloads/

Answer (score 2):

The process of using SCP to copy files from a local machine to an AWS EC2 Linux instance is covered step-by-step (including the points mentioned below) in [this video](https://youtu.be/GFTsU_XRXEg).

To correct this particular issue with using SCP:

1. You need to specify the correct Linux user. From [Amazon](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html):

   - For Amazon Linux, the user name is ec2-user.
   - For RHEL, the user name is ec2-user or root.
   - For Ubuntu, the user name is ubuntu or root.
   - For Centos, the user name is centos.
   - For Fedora, the user name is ec2-user.
   - For SUSE, the user name is ec2-user or root.
   - Otherwise, if ec2-user and root don't work, check with your AMI provider.
2. Your private key must not be publicly visible. Run the following command so that only the root user can read the file.

   ```
   chmod 400 /path/to/yourKeyFile.pem
   ```

Answer (score 0):

First you should change the mode of `.pem` file from read and write mode to read only mode. This can be done just by a single command in terminal `sudo chmod 400 your_public_key.pem`

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the suggestions mentioned above and nothing worked. I terminated the current instance, launched another one and repeated the same exact process. This time no problems. Sometimes it might be the remote ami's fault.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to copy a folder use the "-r" parameter

```
scp -r -i AmazonKey.pem /Users/yourUserName/desktop/yourFolderName ec2-user@ec2-50-17-16-67.compute-1.amazonaws.com:~/.
```

Answer (score 0):

I find a way with aws-cli ssm, this method can work with private subnet instances, the ec2 instance do not need a public ip.

#### step 1: login to EC2 instance with aws ssm start-session

```
aws --profile ${AWS_PROFILE} ssm start-session --target ${targetInstanceId}
```

#### step 2: add public key to the ec2 instance

```
echo ${pubKey} >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

#### step 3: open a port forwarding with aws ssm start-session

```
aws --profile ${AWS_PROFILE} ssm start-session --target ${targetInstanceId} \
    --document-name AWS-StartPortForwardingSession \
    --parameters '{"portNumber":["'${remotePort}'"],"localPortNumber":["'${localPort}'"]}'
echo "${targetInstanceId}:${remotePort} ==> localhost:${localPort}"
```

#### step 4: scp

```
scp -P ${localPort} some/file ec2-user@localhost:/some/path/
```

and you can simplify these steps with ~/.ssh/config and makefile utils. this is my util script:

```
aws --profile ${AWS_PROFILE} ec2 describe-instances | yq '.Reservations.[].Instances.[]
  |select(.State.Name == "running")
  |.InstanceId + " " + .PrivateIpAddress + " " + (.Tags.[]|select(.Key == "Name").Value)' \
| tee out/ec2-running-instances-$ENV.yml | nl

if [[ x${instanceIdx} = x ]]; then
    Input instanceIdx "eg: 1"
fi
sel=$(cat out/ec2-running-instances-$ENV.yml | sed -n ${instanceIdx}p)
set -- $sel
targetInstanceId=$1

if [[ x$forward = x ]]; then # login 
    aws --profile ${AWS_PROFILE} ssm start-session --target ${targetInstanceId}
else # port forward
    if [[ x${remotePort} = x ]]; then
        Input remotePort "eg: 33306"
    fi
    if [[ x${localPort} = x ]]; then
        Input localPort "eg: 33306"
    fi
    echo "${targetInstanceId}:${remotePort} ==> localhost:${localPort}"
    aws --profile ${AWS_PROFILE} ssm start-session --target ${targetInstanceId} \
    --document-name AWS-StartPortForwardingSession \
    --parameters '{"portNumber":["'${remotePort}'"],"localPortNumber":["'${localPort}'"]}'
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use:

`scp -i "path to .pem file" "file to be copeide from local machine" username@amazoninstance: 'destination folder to copy file on remote machine'`