# using scp to transfer files in amazon ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2

I need to copy many files from a remote server (ec2-amazon) to home machine, manually with the WinSCP would take hours.  I found this thread [using scp to copy a file to amazon EC2 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388014/using-scp-to-copy-a-file-to-amazon-ec2-instance) but I need to know how to do it the other way around (from the remote server), my basic try just to request your help:

scp ubuntu@ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:/myfiles/  -r /mypc/folder/

Of course I get:

1) Permission denied (publickey).

2) How should I give the destination in my home machine (IP address?).

I'd appreciate your help!

Zia

Comment: Pass your public key to the scp command `scp -i publickey.pem ...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Steps

1. be in directory where `xxx.pem` file exists
2. run this command

`scp -i "path to xxx.pem" -r ubuntu@ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:/var/www/html /path to some Downloads/`

where `/var/www/html` is target directory in ec2 instance  `/path to some Downloads/` local machine download diretory

-r if it's a directory.