# Deploy Play 2.1 in amazon ec2 instance

Tags: playframework, amazon-ec2, playframework-2.1

I am new to Play framework as well to amazon ec2. I have a play 2.1 application which i want to deploy on amazon ec2. I have amazon microinstance already set up. Is there any guide or steps available that I can follow ?

Answer (score 5):

Use the [dist](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ProductionDist) command from the Play console, then copy the zip on your EC2 server, unzip it, and run your app using the `start` script.

You can also use some other config, take a look at the [doc](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ProductionConfiguration).

And it is also better [to put a HTTP frontend](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/HTTPServer).

Comment: Using the 'start' command starts Play in the foreground. Is it common practice to use & to fork it?

Also, what do they mean by using SIGTERM to terminate the process?

Comment: the start script has been replaced with a script with the same name as the project itself in target/universal/ same process though

Answer (score 4):

See the links attached to each step that you need to take:

1. [Connect to your ec2 instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstances.html)
2. [Install Play](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/Installing)
3. [Copy your application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558080/scp-secure-copy-to-ec2-instance-without-password) (add `-r` option to `scp` if copying the whole folder)
4. [Run the application](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/Production)

Comment: I have a question. Elastic Beanstalk would automatically handle the scaling / load balancing, but since this is being run in an instance, how would that work? Will it be auto scaled, etc?

Comment: this is more of a hack than a proper deployment process. A deploy process must be 1. scalable (you will not deploy to each of the server manually this way), 2. rollback should be possible, 3. smoke tests enabled etc. :)